# Ruby - How to print the actual index number of an array, not the value of that index

Tags: arrays, ruby

got a simple question.

I want to puts the index number of the array, not the actual value of the array index. So if array[0] = book1 I want to puts 0, not book1. How can I do this?

More specifically if it's relevant, in my task I'm printing each album in the array in a loop, but also want to print which number each album is.

```rb
index = 0
    while index < albums.length
        print_album(albums[index])
        index += 1
    end
```

Answer (score 7):

Rubyists would typically not use `while` for iterating over an array. What you want is idiomatically written as follows:

```
albums.each_with_index do |album, index|
  puts "#{index}: #{album}"
end
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I am meant to use a while loop like that in my task, is there any way to do it with my loop?

Comment: Your code is fine, just not idiomatic. However, the printing is hidden in `print_album`, which apparently only accepts the album itself. You already have the variable `index` which you can print. Either just... print it, or modify `print_album` to do so (and to accept the index parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Amadan's answer is absolutely right-- that's how you should do it in Ruby. Using an enumerable is far more idiomatic

```
index = 0
while index < albums.length
    puts "#{index} : #{albums[index]}"
    index += 1
end
```

Is how you would do it using a while loop.